# insertNodeInto function only works in first insertion (works for leaf node)

Tags: java, user-interface, jtree, defaulttreemodel

Say I'm coding for an editable tree file system and adding an action listener for my "add child" button. That is, once I select a node in the tree and click the "Add child" button. There should be a new node "New" becoming its child, which was showed in Fig.1.

(Sorry I don't have 10 reputation to post images.. But probably you can run the complete code below.)

**But the thing is my listener only works in first insertion, which means it only works for leaf node.**

When I'm trying to add a new node into "Thing" node, the tree doesn't change. While the figure didn't change, the return value of .childCount() function return did change according to what the console display.

```
    addChildButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action)
        {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) m_tree.
                getLastSelectedPathComponent();
            if (selectedNode == null)
            {
                System.out.println("selected null");
                return ;
            }
            DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("New");
            System.out.println(selectedNode.getChildCount());
            m_model.insertNodeInto(newNode, selectedNode, 
                selectedNode.getChildCount());
            // display the new node
            m_tree.scrollPathToVisible(new TreePath(newNode.getPath()));
        }
    });
```

For the ones who want to run the program, the complete code is here:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;
public class TreeEditTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new TreeEditFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class TreeEditFrame extends JFrame
{
    public TreeEditFrame()
    {
        setTitle("TreeEditTest");
        setSize(M_DEFAULT_WIDTH, M_DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

        // construct tree
        TreeNode root = makeSampleTree();
        m_model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        m_tree = new JTree(root);
        m_tree.setEditable(true);
        // add scroll pane with tree
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(m_tree);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // make buttons
        makeButtons();  
    }

    private TreeNode makeSampleTree()
    {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Thing");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode pizza = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Pizza");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode pizzaBase = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("PizzaBase");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode pizzaTopping = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("PizzaTopping");
        root.add(pizza);
        root.add(pizzaBase);
        root.add(pizzaTopping);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode deepPanBase = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("DeepPanBase");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode thinAndCrispyBase = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("ThinAndCrispyBase");
        pizzaBase.add(deepPanBase);
        pizzaBase.add(thinAndCrispyBase);

        return root;        
    }

    private void makeButtons()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton addChildButton = new JButton("Add Child");      
        JButton addSiblingButton = new JButton("Add Sibling");
        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete");
        addChildButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action)
            {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) m_tree.
                    getLastSelectedPathComponent();
                if (selectedNode == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("selected null");
                    return ;
                }
                DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("New");
                System.out.println(selectedNode.getChildCount());
                m_model.insertNodeInto(newNode, selectedNode, 
                    selectedNode.getChildCount());

//              display the new node
                m_tree.scrollPathToVisible(new TreePath(newNode.getPath()));
            }
        });
        addSiblingButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action)
            {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) m_tree.
                    getLastSelectedPathComponent();
                if (selectedNode == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("selected null");
                    return ;
                }
                DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) selectedNode.
                    getParent();
                if (parent == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("parent null");                  
                    return ;
                }
                DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("New");
                int selectedIndex = parent.getIndex(selectedNode);
//              System.out.println(parent.getChildCount());             
//              m_model.insertNodeInto(newNode, parent, parent.getChildCount());
                System.out.println(selectedIndex+1);
                m_model.insertNodeInto(newNode, parent, selectedIndex+1);

                // now display the new node
                TreeNode[] nodes = m_model.getPathToRoot(newNode);
                TreePath path = new TreePath(nodes);
                m_tree.scrollPathToVisible(path);
            }
        });
        deleteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action)
            {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode selectedNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) m_tree.
                    getLastSelectedPathComponent();
                if (selectedNode == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("selected null");
                    return ;
                }
                DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) selectedNode.
                    getParent();
                if (parent == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Cannot delete the \"Thing\" node");
                    return ;
                }
                m_model.removeNodeFromParent(selectedNode);
            }
        });
        panel.add(addChildButton);
        panel.add(addSiblingButton);
        panel.add(deleteButton);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    private DefaultTreeModel m_model;
    private JTree m_tree;
    private static final int M_DEFAULT_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int M_DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 200;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's simply because the JTree doesn't use your model. It uses another model it creates from the root tree you passed as argument to the tree constructor. Replace

```
m_tree = new JTree(root);
```

by

```
m_tree = new JTree(m_model);
```

Comment: Many thanks! I'm still wondering why this "add child" listener works for leaf node ; )